# Python lambda expression

Tags: python, lambda

Consider the following:

```
>>> a=2
>>> f=lambda x: x**a
>>> f(3)
9
>>> a=4
>>> f(3)
81
```

I would like for `f` not to change when `a` is changed. What is the nicest way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another option is to create a closure:

```
>>> a=2
>>> f = (lambda a: lambda x: x**a)(a)
>>> f(3)
9
>>> a=4
>>> f(3)
9
```

This is especially useful when you have more than one argument:

```
 f = (lambda a, b, c: lambda x: a + b * c - x)(a, b, c)
```

or even

```
 f = (lambda a, b, c, **rest: lambda x: a + b * c - x)(**locals())
```

Answer (score 13):

You need to bind `a` to a keyword argument when defining the `lambda`:

```
f = lambda x, a=a: x**a
```

Now `a` is a local (bound as an argument) instead of a global name.

Demo:

```
>>> a = 2
>>> f = lambda x, a=a: x**a
>>> f(3)
9
>>> a = 4
>>> f(3)
9
```